# Display Custom Taxonomy by Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to create a function that allows me to display a taxonomy via shortcode.

I try this but doesn't work:

```
function category_in_content($atts){
    global $post;

    return get_the_terms( $post, 'course_category' );
}
add_shortcode( 'catcorso', 'category_in_content' );
```

The taxonomy name is "course_category".

Answer (score 0):

By default [add_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) return html.
You can try the following code:

```
add_shortcode( 'catcorso', 'category_in_content' );
function category_in_content($atts){
    global $post;
    $html  = '';
    $taxonomy = 'course_category';
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post, $taxonomy );

    if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $html .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved with this:

```
function cat_title(){
    global $post;
    $categories = get_the_terms( $post, 'course_category' );

            if ( isset( $categories[0] ) ) {
                return '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $categories[0] ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $categories[0]->name ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
            }       

}
add_shortcode( 'catcorso', 'cat_title' );
```